# MySql data source not showing in visual studio 2017 RC

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2017

I have successfully installed the data source connector on VS2015 but VS2017 is giving me trouble. Is it a case of the connector not supporting VS2017 yet? Anyone managed to make it work?

(Tools > Connect to database...)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Might be helpful for others.
This issue has been fixed in latest version (MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.7) Click on the below link for more details https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,656703,656703#msg-656703

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The people over on [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,653594,653634#msg-653634) MySQL forum post have said that they will look at supporting visual studio 2017 after it goes to GA version.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue.

Use ***devart dotNet connect for MySql***, works wonderfully.....

[PROOF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VJSs.png)

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely give it a look.

Comment: It is available now for 2017... but there are two installers: a "web" installer and a "full" installer.  the "web" installer does not seem to work.  The full installer does though.

the web installer "runs" and seems to install things but vs'17 never sees any of it.